# Does this represent a function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say we have a set, B, of bitstrings, s, of size 8. Does the following represent a functions from B to N?
*f(s) is the number of positions i (i= 0 to 6), where bit$_{i}$ and bit$_{i+1}$ differ*
I am confused by this notation. Shouldn't the number of positions be i (i=0 to 7)? 0-6 gives only 7 positions in a bitstring with 8 0's and 1's. Also, I don't know how to read and interpret this notation. Specifically, the part that says *where bit$_{i}$ and bit$_{i+1}$ differ*. Does this mean we can't have a bitstring s = {11001100} because the first bit is 1 and the second bit is 1 thus not differing? If I am correct then this definiton doesn't describe a set of bitstrings of size 8 since bitstrings with repeating adjacent numbers aren't considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, f(s) is a function from B to N. It only counts positions 0 to 6, because it's always comparing pairs of bits. So in your example bitstring s = {11001100}, if we're counting from the left, then $bit_0 = 1$, $bit_1 = 1$, $bit_2 = 0$, etc., so:

Are $bit_0$ and $bit_1$ different? No, they're both 1.

Are $bit_1$ and $bit_2$ different? Yes, $bit_1$ is 1 and $bit_0$ is 0.

Are $bit_2$ and $bit_3$ different? No, they're both 0.

...

Are $bit_6$ and $bit_7$ different? No, they're both 0.

Then you count up how many times you answered "Yes" to that list of questions, which is 3, and so $f(s) = 3$.

I have no idea what you mean about "describing" the set of bitstrings - $f$ is a *function* that maps bitstrings in the set $B$ to natural numbers in the set $\mathbb{N}$. You can use $f$ to characterise subsets of $B$ - for example, $\{s \in B : f(s) = 3\}$ is the set of all bitstrings with 3 pairs of adjacent bits differing and includes the strings 00000101, 11001100, 10001000, among others.